# When using java 8 map, filter and collect, does it create new objects or modify existing objects?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the code below where I am doing filtering using a filter and replace function inside my map and then I am doing a collect to replace my original array. My question is whether my original objects in inputArr are being discarded and new objects are created or are the same objects being modified when I am doing a collect?

```
public static void test () {
    inputArr.stream().filter(s -> toRemove.contains(s)).
            forEach(u -> u.replaceAll("2","X"));
    inputArr = inputArr.stream().map(x -> filterReplace(x,toRemove)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(inputArr);
}

static String filterReplace(String input, Set<String> toRemove) {
    if (toRemove.contains(input)) {
        return "X";
    }
    else
        return input;
}
```

Comment: Tip: you can replace `s -> toRemove.contains(s)` with `toRemove::contains`.

Comment: @SriK *array*? It looks like `inputArr` is actually a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so if I understood correctly you want to find out if `collect` or `forEach` modifies the original source. You could have easily tested this yourself. Let's have a small class for test:

```
static class MyObject {
    private int value;

    public MyObject(int value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return System.identityHashCode(this) + " " + value;
    }
}
```

And a small usage, firs with `forEach`:

```
    MyObject first = new MyObject(1);
    MyObject second = new MyObject(2);
    List<MyObject> list = Arrays.asList(first, second);

    System.out.println(list);
    list.stream().forEach(x -> x.setValue(x.getValue() + 1));
    System.out.println(list);
```

If you print these:

```
[1018081122 1, 242131142 2]
[1018081122 2, 242131142 3]
```

Notice that its the same *same hash* - objects have not changed inside the list. The references are the same. What you have changed is the *internals* of an Object.

Same thing would happen for `collect`:

```
    System.out.println(list);
    List<MyObject> result = list.stream().filter(x -> x.getValue() > 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
```

There are two main things to get here. *Streams* iterate over the existing source, if inside your stream you change some property (like in `forEach` example), you have **changed the source**.

You should not change the **source of your stream** as this is prohibited by the documentation. This is either called *non-interference* or *side-effects*.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. So in a way, the forEach did cause a side-effect but since it didnt modify the number of items in the input list, this side-effect is fine?  If I were to delete an item in the list within my forEach, that would be prohibited. Is this a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

Any method that modifies a string must return a new object, because strings are immutable by definition. Thus,

```
forEach(u -> u.replaceAll("2","X"))
```

creates a new string for each element in the stream and then immediately discards it, because the return value is ignored.

As for the `filterReplace()` method in the second stream, that's not modifying at all, it simply returns the input string or another predefined value (`"X"`). The original objects in `inputArr` may be discarded once that variable is reassigned, but there are no new objects created within the stream.

Comment: Thanks. But lets say instead of a string, its an object and instead of replaceAll, I am modifying an attribute within the object. In this scenario, is my original array of objects being replaced with a new array of objects or is the .collect modifying the references to the objects in the original list?

Comment: Both. The first stream modifies the existing objects, and the second replaces the list with a new one.